# The transition doesn't work on the .line elements, they change property but the transition is not applied. Is there any ways to enable it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a width animation on an .line div's, from defined 70%/40% to 10%. I've added the transition to .line class (and I've tried to add it everywhere), and it doesn't work, the width is changing, but no transition is used. **How does one enable the transition on the class that is dynamically added?**

I'm using [UIlang](http://uilang.com/) to dynamically add the .hide class, so when the .more button has class .hide, the lines would change width. I've added [CodePen](http://codepen.io/f3lko/pen/vOGWxg/) so you could see whats going on. (I've pulled just this part from my current project, sorry for ugliness). 
If you click less button, the .more button will appear again.

```
  <a class="more">more
    <div class="more-line">
      <div class="line line-70"></div>
      <div class="line line-40"></div>
      <div class="line line-40"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Transition doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I see your confusion, sorry. The transition doesn't work on the .line elements, they change property but the transition is not applied. Is there any ways to enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `display: block;` from line `36`

Comment: Thank you! May I ask why this makes a difference?

Comment: I don't know the technicalities but I'll explain the best I could.
By default, `a` tags have `display: inline` property. When you add the `.hide` class, you're setting the `display` to `block` which kinda breaks the transition of the children because `display` cannot be animated. If you really want `display: block`, you should set it in the initial state and don't change its value within the animation period.